# Проверить на javascript существование cookie

Tags: javascript, cookie

На сайте в куку `OTK` я записываю источник перехода на сайт:

Функция `getCookie` возвращает cookie с именем name, если есть, если нет, то undefined

```html
   
    function getCookie(name) {
        var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
            "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
            ));
        return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
    }
```

Если `OTK` еще не существует, то создадим ее и запишем туда источник перехода

```html
    if ( (getCookie("OTK") === undefined) )
{     
    document.cookie = "OTK=" + escape(document.referrer) +"; expires=" + expire.toUTCString() +";";
}
```

Все это работает криво. Например:

Переходим на сайт извне. `OTK` создалась и там верное значение. Затем перейдем с главной вглубь сайта. На новой странице создается дублирующая кука `OTK`. теперь их 2: в одной правильный реферер, во второй адрес главной страницы моего сайта.

Как переписать проверку куку `OTK` на существование?

Если `OTK` еще не существует или если у нее нулевое значение, то перезаписать туда данные. А если она существует и не пустая, то не трогать ее.

Answer (score 2):

Советую для работы с куками использовать две функции

```js
function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

function setCookie(name, value, options) {
  options = options || {};

  var expires = options.expires;

  if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
    expires = options.expires = d;
  }
  if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
    options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
  }

  value = encodeURIComponent(value);

  var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

  for (var propName in options) {
    updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
    var propValue = options[propName];
    if (propValue !== true) {
      updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
    }
  }

  document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
```

C помощью них ты гарантированно сможешь получить куку и установить ее, если она отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> document.cookie = "OTK=" + escape(document.referrer) +"; expires=" + expire.toUTCString() +";";
> ```

```
... + expire.toUTCString() + ";path=/;"
```